# Electronics at high acceleration

Tags: soldering, shock

I would like to meaure g-force (100 - 4000 g) within a centrifuge (I know it sounds silly because it can be calculated but it is more of a learning thing). I thought of a 3d printed enclosure housing the necessary components (battery, microcontroller, cables, sensor) and some sort of epoxy resin as filler to avoid any parts moving around. 
Is it feasible to use standard consumer electronics for this purpose ? 
Do I have to e.g. cover the microcontroller in epoxy to avoid solder joints braking apart ? I found this resource http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a402987.pdf describing consumer electronics surviving much harder accelerations (10k - 20k g).

Comment: *What* "standard consumer electronics"? 4000g implies that everything is going to have its weight multiplied by 4000.  I would say a standard consumer TV will just collapse into itself.

Comment: e.g. an arduino, a battery, cables and a resistive force sensor and some sort of ADC converter

Comment: I've used standard components (surface-mount and through-hole resistors, capacitors, and ICs) on Terrier-Orion sounding rocket payloads with no issues, but that's probably single 10's of g... I would think that careful design (e.g. orient all components such that the acceleration vector pushes them into the circuit board rather than at an angle to it) would give you a decent chance, but hard to say for sure.

Comment: 20,000 g can be achieved (been there) but the devil is really in the detail on how you mount things and certainly using potting compound is a good idea.

Comment: Remember, epoxy and potting compound effectively insulate items, making them prone to thermal run-away. Design accordingly...

Comment: I looked at the document you cite and it says nothing about using an arduino or battery...they tested a custom board and some of the parts failed. I think the key here is that very specialized construction and mounting techniques are required.

Comment: Worked with a mechanical engineer who designed a 4" cube that ended up in 4,000G situation. He used layers of rubber between the PCBs, and compressed the entire system into those rubber sheets. He had lots of experience at such beasts.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf That must be momentary Gs right? I don't see how rubber sheets would do anything for continuous Gs.